# Unity UI elements not changing when button is clicked

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, button, click

I am making a simple game for Unity and currently there is not much to it other than an opening cut-scene prototype. This consists of simple panels all under one canvas, each panel has a button that is supposed to disable it and enable the next panel.

Thus I start with panel 1 enabled, and under it is a button simply called 'next' When next is clicked it runs OnClick(), first it disables the first panel and then enables the second. This works just fine, however some of the other panels do not have a functioning button even though it is set to do the same thing with a different set of panels.

The later panels are literally duplicates of the first only with different panels set to enabled and disabled when the button is clicked. However some of them simply do not work when we try to click on the button there and thus nothing happens.

I would much appreciate if the people here have any insight on this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this seems barely/not reproduceable for us so it becomes almost impossible to provide a solution here.

Comment: You made a mistake, it should work. I suggest you not repeating code like that. Add a tag for your panels, buttons, then in your code use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to find them and then use a for loop and some logic for setting `onClick` event for all buttons at once.